# Typeerror : cannot read property analytics of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling below method, but on page load this error appears
**cannot read property analytics of undefined javascript**

```
IsAttentiveAvailable();

//Check if Attentive SDK is available for use
  export function IsAttentiveAvailable() {
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.attentive.analytics !== 'undefined')
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
```

Comment: There are [hundreds of answered questions](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+cannot+read+property+of+undefined) about this here on SO. The answers all boil down to: The thing you're trying to use is `undefined`. You need to figure out why (if it shouldn't be) or if it's valid that it's sometimes undefined, avoid using it when it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `optional chaining` to check like this:

```
if (typeof window?.attentive?.analytics !== "undefined") {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Or simply `return !!(typeof window?.attentive?.analytics);`

Comment: How this will work ? @JeremyThille

Comment: `typeof window?.attentive?.analytics` returns a string (like "Object"), which is something truthy (it's not null, or undefined, or zero). When you negate a truthy value with `!`, it gives `false` : `!(typeof window?.attentive?.analytics) == false`. You want to invert it a second time to know if it was truthy in the first place, with another `!`. Which gives `!!(typeof window?.attentive?.analytics) == true`

Comment: It is the same with your logic but more concise.